# Access to apple id account

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I know my apple id (and the email associated with it) but I don't remember the password. This is complicated by the fact that I don't have the phone # associated with account nor do I remember the number.
What can I do?

Comment: Try contacting Apple Support or use the Security Questions.

Comment: Or https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to your account, and you don't know the former number nor do you have access to any Apple devices that your Apple ID is signed into (iPhone, iPad, iPod, or Mac) then **you cannot recover your account**. Account recovery requires no less than the associated Apple ID email and the phone number associated with the account & devices that had access to the account.

Apple's automated ID system can only verify your account with passwords, devices & phone numbers. Emails arent a secure way of identification so they no longer use them to verify you with [two-factor identification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915).

What I would do is backtrack the previous carriers or phone numbers you've used lately. Start with your current carrier and work backwards. If you've ever had your phone number ported over from one carrier to another you need to call the carrier that brought over your number and have them provide you with it.

If you can at least find the phone number, but don't have access to it, then you can go through what's called [Account Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921). Just go to [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/) and enter your Apple ID email address then the phone number on the next page and it will make you go through a waiting process to verify your accounts security (checking for active devices, breaches, etc.)

If you manage to find the number. Comment here because I can explain the recovery process in detail since most people end up waiting longer than expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been looking for phone # but haven't found it yet. Do you know if it is possible to delete the account. I would be fine with starting over, using the same email address associated with the apple id. Also, I have no apple devices.

Comment: You cannot delete the account without access to the account. Apple no longer closes accounts because they no longer have access to them, or their content. Try hunting down older numbers. Otherwise you'll need to make a new Apple ID with a new email address.